# Will tables sorted on the join field still be sorted after a join in Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

I'm working in Apache Pig Latin and trying to determine if I join two tables which are previously sorted on their join field, will the resultant table still be sorted? Will the underlying mapreduce process affect the order of output tuples relative to the key originally sorted on?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably not. Please read the "Usage" part of [ORDER BY](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#ORDER+BY) in the pig latin reference manual.